# Gateway that makes a CMIS server appear as an FTP server

Tags: ftp, cmis

[CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) is a protocol supported by all modern [Enterprise Content Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management) servers.

Some legacy clients don't know the CMIS protocol and can only connect to servers via FTP.

Is there a sort of gateway that would make any CMIS server appear as an FTP server? (FTPS/SFTP is OK too)

FTP client ----> gateway ----> CMIS server

This would be useful for servers that implement CMIS but not FTP, for instance [NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com/).